# Hadoop backend with millions of records insertion

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am new to hadoop, can someone please suggest me how to upload millions of records to hadoop? Can I do this with hive and where can I see my hadoop records?

Until now I have used hive for creation of the database on hadoop and I am accessing it with localhost 50070. But I am unable to load data from csv file to hadoop from terminal. As it is giving me error:

> FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: Line 2:0 Invalid path ''/user/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs'': No files matching path hdfs://localhost:54310/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs

[image: EROOR IN THE TERMINAL:]

Can anyone suggest me some way to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I suppose initially the data is in the Local file system.*

So a simple workflow could be: load data from local to hadoop file system(HDFS), create a hive table over it and then load the data in hive table.

**Step 1:**

```
// put in HDFS
$~ hadoop fs -put /local_path/file_pattern* /path/to/your/HDFS_directory
// check files 
$~ hadoop fs -ls /path/to/your/HDFS_directory
```

**Step 2:**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE if not exists mytable (
Year int, 
name string
) 
row format delimited 
fields terminated by ',' 
lines terminated by '\n'
stored as TEXTFILE;
```

// display table structure

```
describe mytable;
```

**Step 3:**

```
Load data local INPATH '/path/to/your/HDFS_directory'
OVERWRITE into TABLE mytable;
```

// simple hive statement to fetch top 10 records

```
SELECT * FROM mytable limit 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH <local-file-path>` to load the files from local directory to Hive tables.

If you dont specify **LOCAL** , then load command will assume to lookup the given file path from HDFS location to load.

Please refer below link,
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Loadingfilesintotables